# What's the meaning of "by exhaustion"

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

> The question of what is a mathematical object was a deep source of debate in the last part of the eighteenth and first part of nineteenth century. There has only been at best a partial resolution, caused in part by Godel's work in logic and in part **by exhaustion**.

What's the meaning of "by exhaustion"?

- Despair people feel despair in solving the question
- Tired people feel tired to solve the question
- The question was exhausted

Answer (score 2):

*Exhaustive research* means that you have thoroughly examined every possible aspect that could be researched (you have *exhausted* all possibilities; there are no possibilities left). One [definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exhaustive):

> **ex·haus·tive** adj.
>
> 1. Treating all parts or aspects without omission; thorough: *an exhaustive study.*

So what is being said in the sentence you quote is that the resolution that has occured is partly due to Godel's work and partly due to the fact that *all other possibilities have been exhausted*, so what is left must be true. So the theory has been proven by the process of elimination; if nothing else is true, this must be. This is aptly described by this quote from Sherlock Holmes:

> "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."

Answer (score 1):

I think here "by exhaustion" means "by a thorough study of the subject." See [the third explanation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exhaust).

It is unthinkable to interpret the phrase as meaning that mathematicians are despair or tired of the question; their job is to answer the question, after all.